# Libre Office Math - Characters not showing up

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, special-characters

I opened Libre Office Math and noticed that all of the mathematical characters are broken and look like squares. What should I do so that these characters appear normally?

[image: Broken Characters]

If anyone's wondering, [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AkeC.png) is how it should look like

Comment: I think that's the intended look of this pane. It's the same on my system. How do you expect it to look?

Answer (score 2):

Your picture looks like normal LibreOffice Math window. So nothing looks broken.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/666663)

Comment: @George: I disagree. That's actually the correct answer (and even if it weren't it's an acceptable answer to say "there's actually no problem here, you're just misunderstanding things because…").

Comment: If your question is deleted (and with the current reviewer votes it looks like it will be deleted) you can flag it for moderator attention and ask for it to be reopened based on what I just wrote.